# Retrieve cmd to php from shellscript but using pgsql select or ssh select

Tags: php, shell

Hello I am trying to retrieve query data when I run my shell script how can the information be printed?

**Performing this way I get return.**

**result**

```
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 876 Aug 22 13:05 Index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 462 Aug 22 13:05 index2.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48 Aug 22 13:05 layout.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  69 Aug 22 13:05 promp.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60 Aug 22 13:05 teste.sh
```

**My php**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -l');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

**my command i tried dont work.**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('psql -X -A -d totalipdb -U totalip -h 10.11.12.193 -t -c "select * from trunks where phone_number = '080078795';"');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

**Retrieve error**

```
localhost cannot fulfill this request at this time.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

running directly in the terminal I have return of query results, but php displays the error

Comment: Performing this way I get return.
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -l');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>                            



total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 876 Aug 22 13:05 Index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 462 Aug 22 13:05 index2.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48 Aug 22 13:05 layout.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  69 Aug 22 13:05 promp.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  60 Aug 22 13:05 teste.sh